# AdminBro - Failed to upload image

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, admin-bro, adminjs

**admin-bro and sequelize failed to upload image.** It still works on **Edit** but not on **New**. It doesn't show the error at any other line in the code.

**Installed libraries and their versions**
"admin-bro": "^2.2.4",
"admin-bro-expressjs": "^2.0.2",
"admin-bro-mongoose": "^0.5.0",
"admin-bro-sequelize": "^1.1.1",

**AdminBroOptions with schema**

```
const options = {
  properties: {
    images: {
      components: {
        edit: AdminBro.bundle('./components/upload-image.edit.tsx'),
        list: AdminBro.bundle('./components/upload-image.list.tsx'),
        show: AdminBro.bundle('./components/upload-image.show.tsx')
      },
    },
  },
  actions: {
    new: {
       after: async (response, request, context) => {
         return uploadAfterHook(response, request, context);
       },
       before: async (response, request, context) => {
        return uploadBeforeHook(request, context);
       }
    },
    edit: {
      after: async (response, request, context) => {
        return uploadAfterHook(response, request, context);
      },
      before: async (request, context) => {
        return uploadBeforeHook(request, context);
      },
    },
  },
};
```

**Here are my hooks (before and after).**

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const AdminBro = require('admin-bro');


/** @type {AdminBro.After<AdminBro.ActionResponse>} */
const after = async (response, request, context) => {

  console.log('on after hook of opal');
  const { record, uploadImage } = context;

  if (record.isValid() && uploadImage) {
    const filePath = path.join('uploads', 'opals', record.id().toString(), uploadImage.name);
    await fs.promises.mkdir(path.dirname(filePath), { recursive: true });

    await fs.promises.rename(uploadImage.path, filePath);

    await record.update({ images: `/${filePath}` });

    response.record.params.image = filePath;
  }
  return response;
};

/** @type {AdminBro.Before} */
const before = async (request, context) => {
  console.log('on before hook of opal');

  if (request.method === 'post') {
    const { images, ...otherParams } = request.payload;

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
    context.uploadImage = images;
    return {
      ...request,
      payload: otherParams,
    };
  }
  return request;
};

module.exports = { after, before };
```

**I am using mysql database using admin-bro-sequelize adapter and below is my model (entity).**

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    'test_db',
    'byal',
    'byal-f',
     {
       host: 'localhost',
       dialect: 'mysql'
     }
);

   
sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', error);
});


const Opals = sequelize.define("opals", {   
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
      allowNull: false
    },
    type: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
        allowNull: true
    },
    images: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('long'),
        allowNull: true,
    },
    color: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
      allowNull: true
    },
    grading: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
      allowNull: true
    },
    region: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
      allowNull: true
    },
    weight: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT('medium'),
      allowNull: true
    },
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT('long'),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    isAvailable: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true,
        allowNull: true
    },
    inactive: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
        allowNull: true
    },
    views: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 1,
      allowNull: true
    }
 });
 
sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    console.log('Opals table created successfully!');
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Unable to create opals table : ', error);
});

module.exports = Opals;
```

How can I fix this? What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the difference is that I am storing the images into the DB as base64. However my problem was with the rec id. You can check my working code here: `if (record && record.isValid() && uploadImage) { await record.update({ image: uploadImage }); } return response;` https://pastebin.com/1uMRFpM9

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).